# Unable to install the car package in R Studio in Windows 10

Tags: r

I'm running RStudio v1.2.5019.

The User folder on my laptop where the packages are stored is *C:\Users\R Shiva*

I am trying to install packages including car but I'm getting the following error.

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/R Shiva/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependency ‘carData’


  There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
        binary source needs_compilation
carData  3.0-2  3.0-3             FALSE
car      3.0-4  3.0-5             FALSE

installing the source packages ‘carData’, ‘car’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/carData_3.0-3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 995544 bytes (972 KB)
downloaded 972 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/car_3.0-5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 504300 bytes (492 KB)
downloaded 492 KB

Warning: invalid package 'C:\Users\R'
Warning: invalid package 'Shiva\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpU7R8OM/downloaded_packages/carData_3.0-3.tar.gz'
Error: ERROR: no packages specified
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘carData’ had non-zero exit status
Warning: invalid package 'C:\Users\R'
Warning: invalid package 'Shiva\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpU7R8OM/downloaded_packages/car_3.0-5.tar.gz'
Error: ERROR: no packages specified
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘car’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\R Shiva\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpU7R8OM\downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: Try to install the package as another user who does not have your username **`R Shiva`**.

Comment: Is it the errror because of the space in the user name?

Comment: Space in your user name is probably the issue. If you can't change that, one fix is to define `R_LIBS_USER` in an `Renviron` file and set it to a location without spaces.

Comment: @ help-info-de and @ neilfws Thank you very much